# What's YAML standards for? I just Google and however I cannot find the answer

Tags: yaml

What's YAML standards for? I just search inweb but I cannot find the answer ...
Hopely, somebody can help
I just help some one find their answer, and would like to get feedback.

Answer (score 1):

YAML is in the category as XML and JSON. They are used to store data, such as config files. Each has strengths and weaknesses. E.g. JSON is more efficient in many applications, but is less human readable. JSON also does not support comments. YAML has many of the features of XML but is less verbose.

Answer (score 1):

YAML is just like a more simplified and human-readable version of JSON. YAML is mostly used by applications to store their configuration files.
For example, Drupal, a content management system (CMS), is now based on Symfony, a PHP framework, that uses YAML for its configuration files.